# Schema indexing in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have created schema indexes in my database using following code.

```
index_1 = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("USER")).on("username").create();
index_2 = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("UNIVERSITY")).on("university_name").create();
index_3 = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label("COLLEGE")).on("college_name").create();
```

Very first time when I start my database, indexes work properly. Then I insert some nodes into the database and then query the database to return the nodes having label "UNIVERSITY". First time it works perfectly and showed me correct result. I wrote following code to display all nodes having label "UNIVERSITY".

```
try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx();)
{
ResourceIterator <Node> univ = graphdb.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label("UNIVERSITY"), "university_name", UNIV_NAME).iterator();

while(univ.hasNext())
 {
    System.out.println("College node "+id++ + " " + univ.next().getProperty("name"));

 }

univ.close();
tx.success();
}
```

Then I shut down the database. But next time when I will start the database and query the database to return the nodes having label "UNIVERSITY", it does not return the nodes. univ.hasNext() becomes false and it does not execute while loop.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: did you use the same database directory? Which Neo4j version did you use?

Comment: yes I am using same database directory. I am using neo4j 2.0

Comment: could you query the schema for the index definitions ? Could you alternatively try a cypher statement like `MATCH (n:UNIVERSITY) return count(*)` and `MATCH (n:UNIVERSITY {university_name='xxx'}) return n`

Comment: yes i have queried the schema for index definitions by using following statements.

//Iterator <IndexDefinition> users = schema.getIndexes().iterator();  
   //System.out.println(schema.getIndexState(users.next()).toString());

and it returns all the three index definitions. Actually I am using java AWT script as frontend to insert the data into database. is that create any problems?

Comment: No it won't you just have to make sure that your operations are kept in the same thread and you don't accidentally use the same transaction in the event-thread and a background thread.

Comment: Do you have any data in the database? Perhaps your transaction was not correctly closed? Try GlobalGraphOperations.at(gdb).getAllNodes()